# Post files and object in the same AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, http-post

I have some data and files that should be posted in one same `AJAX` request. Tried some solutions but I always get `null` in the controller (files are sent fine and when I change `Tester` class to simple `string` it also works).

My JS:

```
function sendAjaxWithFile (formData, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    successCallback = successCallback || function () { };
    errorCallback = errorCallback || function () { };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Test/Save",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: successCallback,
        error: errorCallback
    });
}

var data = new FormData();
data.append("tester", { Name: "QWERTY" });
data.append("someFile", file);

$scope.sendAjaxWithFile(data, function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
}, function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
});
```

And the server side code:

```
[AjaxOnly]
[HttpPost]
[Route("Save")]
public async Task<JsonResult> Save(Tester tester, HttpPostedFileBase someFile)
{
    return await Task.FromResult(Json(0));
}
```

`Tester` class:

```
public class Tester
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: provide the tester class and relevent html please

Comment: It may not matter, but, try `{ "Name": "QWERTY" }` => quotes around `Name`

Comment: Still null in the controller :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a workaround, because I don't think it can be resolved in a normal way...

My solution is to send string data which is serialized from my `JS` object.

```
data.append("serializedJsonString", JSON.stringify({ Name: "QWERTY" })); // I can serialize what I want to
```

I needed to change the parameter of my `Save` method to get `JSON` string data and convert it into `Tester` class manually:

```
[AjaxOnly]
[HttpPost]
[Route("Save")]
public async Task<JsonResult> Save(string serializedJsonString, HttpPostedFileBase someFile)
{
    var decodedJson = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(serializedJsonString);
    var jTester = JObject.Parse(decodedJson);
    var tester = new Tester { Name = jTester["Name"].ToString() };

    return await Task.FromResult(Json(0));
}
```